# Display site logo in custom email template

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to display the site logo in one of the sections of my New account email confirmation template. So basically when the user signup they receive an email of the account creation. Now I want to customize this content. I went to `Marketing -> Communication -> Email Template` and change my template content. Below is what I get

```
<tr>
  <td valign="top">
    <a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{skin url="images/logo_email.gif" _area='frontend'}}" alt="{{var store.getFrontendName()}}"  style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Now I'm wondering why my Site logo is not displaying. Honestly, I don't know if this is the correct code to display the actual site logo in the email. When I view the email in my email client I get a broken site logo. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: please explain using screenshot ...

Comment: you are using magento 1 email template code, this will not work in Magento 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code you are referring is for magento 1.

You can try below code:

```
<tr>
  <td valign="top">
    <a href="{{store url=""}}">
    <img src="{{view url="images/slide-bg.jpg"}}" alt="{{trans "%store_name" store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}"  style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The src should be replace right? What is the filename being used for the email site logo?

Comment: if you want to use default logo, you can use `src="{{var logo_url}}`